# Update large number of documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update the content of large number of documents in firebase, I have tried the following:

First, reading all documents on client side and looping over the documents and updating them by refence.
the problem here is that I am doing intensive operation on the client side and that would be unpredictable, therefore I switched to Firebase's Functions.

Second, reading all documents in firebase functions and then updating them using [bulkwriter](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/bulkwriter)

here's the code:

```
exports.testingFunction1 = functions.runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: "8GB",
}).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const storeId = data.text;
    if (!(typeof storeId === 'string') || storeId.length === 0) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'one arguments containing the storeId.');
    }

    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
    const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
    const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
    let bulk1 = new admin.firestore().bulkWriter();
    let products = await admin.firestore().collection("Products").get(); //here's the problems's source
    products.forEach((document) => {
        bulk1.update(document.ref, { "IsStorePublished": true });

    });

    await bulk1.flush().then(() => {
        return { "result": "Success!" };
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
        });


    return { "Result": "Success" }

});
```

the problem here appears when I try to read more that about 8000 documents at a single time, I get  the following error although I have changed the memory limitations for the function to the max possible:

> FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory

[image]

Is there a good way to achieve this task ?

Comment: Can you share the code that is not working as intended?

Comment: I guess you're sure you've updated the memory limit (and deployed, if done locally). Are you sure decreasing the number of documents solves the issue? The maximum is 8GB, and I'd assume those documents cannot be that big :) Wildguessing I'd say the issue is elsewhere

Comment: I have actually tested using the same code with limiting the get to 1000 documents, and it didn't produce any problem, and when limiting to 8000 or making it unlimited, it produces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I have solved the issue as following:

the problem with reading a large amount of data to update it in firebase functions is that the memory is filling up, so I have made a recursive function enables reading 500 items at a time and apply the "BulkWrite" to only 500 documents at the time, and to achieve this I used the  "startAfter" reading method.

This is the main firebase v1 function:

where it reads the first 500 items and apply the function "operationToDo" to them, and then calls the recursive function to continue the process.

```
exports.testingFunction1 = functions.runWith({

    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: "8GB",
}).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {


    const storeId = data.text;
    if (!(typeof storeId === 'string') || storeId.length === 0) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'one arguments "storeId" containing the storeId.');
    }
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }

    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
    const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
    const email = context.auth.token.email || null;


    let first = admin.firestore()
        .collection("Products")
        .orderBy("Name").where("Store", '==', storeId)
        .limit(500);

    await first.get().then(
        async (documentSnapshots) => {

            if (documentSnapshots.docs.length == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                await operationToDo(documentSnapshots, "update", { "IsStorePublished": false })
            }

            let lastVisible =
                documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.size - 1];

            await recursivePublishingTheStore(lastVisible, storeId);
        },
    );

    return { "Result": "Success" }
});
```

The recursive function:

```
async function recursivePublishingTheStore(lastVisible, storeId) {
    let next = admin.firestore()
        .collection("Products")
        .orderBy("Name").where("Store", '==', storeId)
        .startAfter(lastVisible)
        .limit(500);
    await next.get().then(
        async (documentSnapshots) => {
            if (documentSnapshots.docs.length == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                await operationToDo(documentSnapshots, "update", { "IsStorePublished": false })
                let lastVisible =
                    documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.size - 1];
                await recursivePublishingTheStore(lastVisible, storeId);
            }
        }

    );
}
```

The operation can be anything but in my case it would be "update":

```
async function operationToDo(documents, operation, value) {
    let bulk1 = new admin.firestore().bulkWriter();
    documents.forEach((document) => {
        if (operation == 'update')
            bulk1.update(document.ref, value);
    });
    await bulk1.flush().then(() => {
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
        });

}
```

The performance of the code above is pretty good, for **updating** about **15k documents** it would take about **2 minutes**.

Note: I have chosen the number 500 randomly, different number might work and might perform better, and I will be experimenting with it this week.